# Having problems with @variable and Cursor in SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, variables, cursor

--Not sure I am doing this right except what I am doing does not work. I have a list of (vend_num) that I need to run through a query one at a time and compile the results. If any can see/explain where I have gone off the rails it would be greatly appreciated. I have been combing the internet and this site and cannot seem to wrap my brain around it.

```
--drop table ##ENE_vendUpdate            
if object_id('tempdb..##ENE_vendUpdate') is not null            
begin            
    drop table ##ENE_vendUpdate          
end  

select vend_num             
into ##ENE_vendUpdate
from vendor 
--select * from  ##ENE_vendUpdate

if @@ROWCOUNT > 0             
BEGIN             
 declare @vend_num varchar(7)                      


declare warrwebcur cursor            
for            
select vend_num from ##ENE_vendUpdate             

open warrwebcur            
fetch warrwebcur into @vend_num      

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0            

BEGIN

Select a.vend_num,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM po 
    join matltran mtl on mtl.ref_num = po.po_num 
    join vendor v on v.vend_num = po.vend_num 
    where v.vend_num = @vend_num 
    AND cast(po.CreateDate as datetime) > DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())   
    AND mtl.reason_code = 'PPQ') 
AS TOTAL_RMAS, 
    (SELECT count(*) 
    FROM vendor v 
    join po on v.vend_num = po.vend_num 
    join vendaddr on vendaddr.vend_num = v.vend_num 
    join PoItem poi on poi.po_num = po.po_num 
    where v.vend_num = @vend_num 
    AND cast(poi.rcvd_date as datetime) > DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())   
    AND poi.stat IN ('C','F')) 
AS  PO_Lines_Complete,
    (SELECT count(*) 
    FROM vendor v 
    join po on v.vend_num = po.vend_num 
    join vendaddr on vendaddr.vend_num = v.vend_num 
    join PoItem poi on poi.po_num = po.po_num where v.vend_num = @vend_num
    AND cast(poi.rcvd_date as datetime) > DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())) 
AS  PO_Lines_Total,
    (SELECT sum(qty) 
    FROM po 
    join matltran mtl on mtl.ref_num = po.po_num 
    join vendor v on v.vend_num = po.vend_num 
    where v.vend_num = @vend_num 
    AND cast(po.CreateDate as datetime) > DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())  
    AND mtl.reason_code = 'PPQ')
AS RMA_Pieces ,
    (SELECT sum(poi.qty_received)
    FROM vendor v 
    join po on v.vend_num = po.vend_num 
    join vendaddr on vendaddr.vend_num = v.vend_num 
    join PoItem poi on poi.po_num = po.po_num where v.vend_num = @vend_num 
    AND cast(poi.rcvd_date as datetime) > DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE()) 
    AND poi.stat in ('C','F') ) 
AS PCs_Received,
    (SELECT sum(poi.qty_ordered)
    FROM vendor v 
    join po on v.vend_num = po.vend_num 
    join vendaddr on vendaddr.vend_num = v.vend_num 
    join PoItem poi on poi.po_num = po.po_num where v.vend_num = @vend_num 
    AND cast(poi.rcvd_date as datetime) > DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE()) AND poi.stat in ('C','F')) 
AS PCs_Due,
    (SELECT count(*)
    FROM vendor v 
    join po on v.vend_num = po.vend_num 
    join vendaddr on vendaddr.vend_num = v.vend_num 
    join PoItem poi on poi.po_num = po.po_num
    where v.vend_num = @vend_num 
    AND poi.rcvd_date <= poi.due_date 
    AND cast(poi.rcvd_date as datetime) > DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE()) ) 
AS PO_Lines_OnTime,
    (SELECT count(*)
    FROM vendor v 
    join po on v.vend_num = po.vend_num 
    join vendaddr on vendaddr.vend_num = v.vend_num 
    join PoItem poi on poi.po_num = po.po_num 
    where v.vend_num = @vend_num 
    AND cast(po.CreateDate as datetime) > DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE()) 
    AND  poi.rcvd_date is null) 
AS  PO_Lines_due,
    (select count(*)
    FROM vendor v 
    join po on v.vend_num = po.vend_num 
    join vendaddr on vendaddr.vend_num = v.vend_num 
    join PoItem poi on poi.po_num = po.po_num  
    where v.vend_num = @vend_num  
    AND cast(poi.rcvd_date as datetime) > DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE()) 
    AND poi.stat in ('C','F')) 
AS ONTIME_PERCT,
    (select count(*)
    FROM vendor v 
    join po on v.vend_num = po.vend_num 
    join vendaddr on vendaddr.vend_num = v.vend_num 
    join PoItem poi on poi.po_num = po.po_num
    where v.vend_num = @vend_num AND cast(poi.rcvd_date as datetime) > DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE()) 
    AND poi.stat in ('C','F')) 
AS TOTAL_ROW_COUNT,
    (SELECT count(*) 
    FROM vendor v 
    join po on v.vend_num = po.vend_num 
    join vendaddr on vendaddr.vend_num = v.vend_num 
    join PoItem poi on poi.po_num = po.po_num
    where v.vend_num = @vend_num 
    AND cast(poi.rcvd_date as datetime) > DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())  
    AND poi.stat IN ('C','F') 
    AND poi.qty_ordered <> poi.qty_received) 
AS  PO_Lines_Accurate

FROM (SELECT DISTINCT v.vend_num FROM vendor v
                                    join po on v.vend_num = po.vend_num
                                    join vendaddr on vendaddr.vend_num = v.vend_num
                                    join PoItem poi on poi.po_num = po.po_num
where v.vend_num = @vend_num AND cast(poi.rcvd_date as datetime) > DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())

 ) A
```

Comment: You didn't tell us what the problem is.  Are you getting an error?  Incorrect results?  Do you really need to add all those lines of code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: When I execute it gives me all the same counts for every @vend_num. There are 3000 and I need to pull all the counts for each of them. If I do it from SSRS and input one vend_num it works fine but I am trying to restructure it so that ALL vend_num's run at once. User cant do 3000 one at a time.

Comment: as I mentioned, your repro above is incorrect, so using the answer below, plug your query where it says to, that should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your TSQL doesn't look complete.  It should look something like this:

```
DECLARE warrwebcur CURSOR FOR
select vend_num from ##ENE_vendUpdate

OPEN warrwebcur
FETCH NEXT FROM warrwebcur INTO @vend_num

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
      -- your query
      FETCH NEXT FROM warrwebcur INTO @vend_num
END 

CLOSE warrwebcur 
DEALLOCATE warrwebcur
```